# React Native Fetch API get method for response JSON

Tags: react-native, networking, fetch

I am trying to get access to the following API endpoint:

```
[
  {
    "location_id": 73,
    "location_name": "Aunt Mary's Great Coffee Shop",
    "location_town": "London",
    "latitude": 74.567,
    "longitude": 102.435,
    "photo_path": "http://cdn.coffida.com/images/78346822.jpg",
    "avg_overall_rating": 4.5,
    "avg_price_rating": 4.3,
    "avg_quality_rating": 4,
    "avg_clenliness_rating": 3.8,
    "location_reviews": [
      {
        "review_id": 643,
        "overall_rating": 4,
        "price_rating": 2,
        "quality_rating": 3,
        "clenliness_rating": 5,
        "review_body": "Great coffee, but the bathrooms stank!",
        "likes": 4654
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

using the following Fetch request:

```
  getsearchData = async () => {
    const value =  await AsyncStorage.getItem('@session_token');
    return fetch('http://10.0.2.2:3333/api/1.0.0/find/', {
      headers: {
        'X-Authorization': value,
      },
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          return response.json();
        } else if (response.status === 401) {
          ToastAndroid.show('Your not logged in', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
        } else {
          throw 'something went wrong';
        }
      })
      .then((responseJson) => {
        //setIsLoading(false);
        this.setState({
            isLoading: false,
            locations: responseJson,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

I am able the access the first object like so:

```
<Text>ID: {parseInt(item.location_id)}</Text>
```

however if i want to access say the overall rating or review body i am not sure how to do so?

```
 <Text>Review ID: {item.review_location_id}</Text>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you used map method on your data in order to render it and access the properties values, you can use same syntax to access other properties, but if you want to access to nested array of object properties values, i mean "location_reviews" or any other in the future, you need to map on that prop as well, since it's array that contain object.
Assuming your code looks like this:

```
{data.map(item => (<Text>ID: {parseInt(item.location_id)}</Text>)}

to access location_reviews.review_id for example, you have to map on internal array 
as well

{data.map(item => (<Text>{item.location_reviews.map(item => item.review_id)}</Text>))}
```

I've created snack for you to play more with it [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@shevchenko27/data-example)

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/p7yWdDNmx ive made a snack with the code i have created - i used a flatlist rather than a map

Comment: it doesn't matter, your prop contains [Object] value, you need to map on it anyway to access to values, see my snack again, it's updated with the view that you have https://snack.expo.io/@shevchenko27/data-example